# Wrap every four posts within a div

Tags: loop

am trying to wrap every row of wordpress posts with a div with a class of row.

Have been trying to follow the answers from another question linked below But seem to be having trouble as my loop is a little different. Also I would like any rows with 1 or more posts to be wrapped in a row also...

I need to wrap every 4 wordpress posts in a div

```
   <?php query_posts('cat=2'); 

        $i = 0;
        $wrap_div = "<div class='row'>";

        if ( have_posts() ) : 
            $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
            echo $wrap_div;

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>



<div class="four columns gameListing" id="" data-count="">       
    <img class="gameLogo" src="" > 
    <div class="gameInfo">
        <h2 class="gameTitle"></h2>
        <div class="gameRating"></div>
    </div>
    <a class="gameCta" rel="" data-post-id="" >
         <span class="title" data-id="">Click to Play</span
    </a>
</div>

<?php 

                if ( $i % 4 == 0 && $i != 0 && ( $i + 1 ) != $total_posts ) {
                    echo '</div>' . $wrap_div;
                }
                $i ++;


                ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Hello @James - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Could you please explain why your current solution "isn't working?" What specifically is it doing that it should not be? Please read the [ask] section of our [help] for more tips on what goes into a good question.

Comment: Please don´t crosspost here and on "normal" SO. I think it´s not really appreciated.

Comment: This has been asked so many times … Please use our search before you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
            <?php
              $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC','cat' => '2',
              );
              $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            <?php if( $loop->have_posts() ): ?>


                  <?php $counter = 0; while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if ($counter % 4 == 0 && $counter != 0): ?>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($counter % 4 == 0 or $counter == 0): ?>
                      <div>
                      <div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                      <div>
                      <div>
                      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                      </div>                                                
                      </div>
                    <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>        
                    </div>
                  </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

That's a sample code I use in this kind of situations and works like a charm. Just replace the necessary divs with your custom game divs.